# Using MPI Derived Datatypes

Tags: mpi, derived-types

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754090/mpi-and-c-structs), I am still wondering the best way to send C/C++ struct data. In fact, I have decided to use derived types, but I am running into problems.

Immediately after `MPI_Init(...)`, I have a function written in a separate file (MPI_NewTypes.cpp/h)  that basically is used to commit new datatypes. Here is  a snapshot:

```
int loop_counter;
    msgInstallP InstallPStruct;
    MPI_Datatype MPI_MSGINSTALLP;
    MPI_Datatype type[4] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_CHAR};
    int blocklen[4] = {
                        sizeof(InstallPStruct.type),
                        sizeof(InstallPStruct.location),
                        sizeof(InstallPStruct.processID),
                        sizeof(InstallPStruct.name)
                      };

    MPI_Aint     disp[4];
    int          base;
    MPI_Address( &InstallPStruct,                disp);
    MPI_Address( &InstallPStruct.location,       disp+1);
    MPI_Address( &InstallPStruct.processID,      disp+2);
    MPI_Address( &InstallPStruct.name,           disp+3);
    base = disp[0];

    for (loop_counter=0; loop_counter < 4; loop_counter++)
      {
        disp[loop_counter] = disp[loop_counter] - base;
      }

    MPI_Type_struct(
                    4, /*count of elements */
                    blocklen, /* array_of_blocklengths */
                    disp, /* array_of_displacements */
                    type, /* array_of_types */
                    &MPI_MSGINSTALLP /* newtype */
                    );

    MPI_Type_commit( &MPI_MSGINSTALLP);
```

After a couple of function calls to functions implemented in different files, I am using the new datatype: `MPI_MSGINSTALLP`. However, my linker complains that it does not know what this new derived type is. Ostensibly, this is a C/C++ scopinq question, but I am not getting it right. How do I make sure that whenever I use the new derived datatype, MPI will know that it exists? I would not want to redo all commits every time I use this new type in the application.

I tried putting this in the MPI_NewTypes.h header file:
`MPI_Datatype MPI_MSGINSTALLP`

hoping that mpic++ would see it, if I included this header in the file which uses the new datatype.

No luck.

Any help?

Per suggestion, here is the top level file which initiates MPI:

```
 #include <atomic>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Fifo.h"
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include "GlobalSettings.h"
#include "Run.h"
#include "Add_MPI_Types.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int myrank;
  int desired_thread_support = MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE;
  int provided_thread_support;

  MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, desired_thread_support, &provided_thread_support);

  /* check if the thread support has been provided */
  if (provided_thread_support!=desired_thread_support)
    {
      std::cout << "MPI thread support not available! Aborted. " << std::endl;
    }

  MPI_Comm_set_errhandler(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERRORS_RETURN);

  Add_MPI_Types();

  /* get rank information */
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);

  /* Rank 0 is always the master, other ranks are slaves */
  if (MASTERNODE == myrank)
    {
      /* run the wrapper for master node */
      run(MASTERAPPLICATION);
    }
  else
    {
      /* run the wrapper for the slave node */
      run(SLAVEAPPLICATION);
    }
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Here, `Add_MPI_Types();` is the function that commits a new data-type, residing in the MPI_NewTypes.cpp/h file (already shown).

The `run(...)` function is also defined in another file, which actually tries to do MPI-Send/Recv:

```
  msgInstallP InstallPMessage;
  InstallPMessage = *(msgInstallP*)Data;
  //Add_MPI_msgInstallP_Type();
  MPI_Ssend(
            (void*)&InstallPMessage,             /* Payload */
            sizeof(msgInstallP),                 /* size of the payload */
            MPI_MSGINSTALLP,                      /* MPI Data type */
            InstallPMessage.location,             /* location to which the message is being sent */
            InstallPMessage.type,                 /* Tag */
            MPI_COMM_WORLD                        /* Communicator */
            );
```

where msgInstallP is a C/C++ struct type (and its equivalent in MPI is MPI_MSGINSTALLP). The MPI_MSGINSTALLP.h does not contain anything, other than the interface declaration for the function `Add_MPI_Types()`.

Please let me know if more detail is required.

Comment: Can you post an example of your actual message passing code? It does look like a scoping problem, which are fairly difficult to debug without context. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely a scoping problem. `MPI_MSGINSTALLP` is just a plain old variable of type `MPI_Datatype`, not a special literal that you can use anywhere once committed (which is basically the way you're trying to use it). Since the variable is temporary within `Add_MPI_Types()`, it long ceased to exist by the time `run()` is called.

Personally, I would move the declaration of `MPI_MSGINSTALLP` inside `run()`, add an `MPI_Datatype&` to the parameters of `Add_MPI_Types()`, and pass `MPI_MSGINSTALLP` to it, so that `run()` looks like this:

```
msgInstallP InstallPMessage;
InstallPMessage = *(msgInstallP*)Data;
MPI_Datatype MPI_MSGINSTALLP;
Add_MPI_Types(MPI_MSGINSTALLP);
//Add_MPI_msgInstallP_Type();
MPI_Ssend(
            (void*)&InstallPMessage,             /* Payload */
            sizeof(msgInstallP),                 /* size of the payload */
            MPI_MSGINSTALLP,                      /* MPI Data type */
            InstallPMessage.location,             /* location to which the message is being sent */
            InstallPMessage.type,                 /* Tag */
            MPI_COMM_WORLD                        /* Communicator */
            );
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, and I could make it work. But, the question is about feasibility. I was hoping that I could make a function call and get the new data types committed, and then reuse it anywhere in the project, which happens to be rather large. I did some more reading, and, if I understood it correctly, everytime, the new data type is used, it needs to be committed, and then deallocated. So, if I am doing dozens of sends and receives in parallel threads, in different file scopes, it would quickly get ugly.

Comment: You only need to define and commit a datatype once, and you can reuse it as long as its typemap is still correct (i.e. it doesn't represent some dynamic data structure that changes between communications). `MPI_MSGINSTALLP` looks like it's static, so all you need to do is make sure it's visible from everywhere. For example, move the definition of `MPI_MSGINSTALLP` and the call to `Add_MPI_Types(MPI_MSGINSTALLP)` to the beginning of your program, and pass a reference to `MPI_MSGINSTALLP` to any function that needs it. Or risk a [velociraptor attack](http://xkcd.com/292/) and make it global. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am going to try this again when I have time. For now, I bypassed the mess with MPI_Pack and MPI_Unpack.