# Why not use MPI_BYTE always?

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi

If I do not have to care about portability on heterogeneous systems (endianity...):

Why not use MPI_BYTE for all communication?

Especially for collectives and when dealing with composed data types, that would make life much easier.

**edit:** I just found [MPI and C structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754090/mpi-and-c-structs) . The answers are applicable to my question.

Comment: Ahhh yes, I find all those integers and floating-point numbers, all those booleans and characters a helluva lot of trouble too.  Mind you, I'm a bit suspicious of anyone who wants to use BYTES, what's wrong with BITS ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: so... what IS wrong with bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you send a slice of a 3-dimensional NxNxN array using types:

```
double array[N][N][N];

 /* ... */

MPI_Datatype xslice, yslice, zslice;

int starts[3]   = {0,N-2,0};
int sizes[3]    = {N,N,N};
int subsizes[3] = {N,2,N};

MPI_Type_create_subarray(3, sizes, subsizes, starts, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &yslice);
MPI_Type_commit(&yslice);

/* ... */

MPI_Send(&(array[0][0][0]), 1, yslice, neigh, ytag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

What's the easier, typing-less, way to do that using only `MPI_BYTE` and no other type constructors?

*All* of high performance computing ends up coming down to understanding memory and data layout, and using higher-level abstractions helps with that.

If you are having trouble with `MPI_Type_create_struct`, you've come to the right place (or one of them).  If you've come to find someone to agree with you that yes, learning new stuff is too hard and not worth it, you're probably in the wrong place.

**Edited to add:**. I agree that structs are a pain to deal with for serialization - not just MPI - in C and Fortran, for which I blame their inexcusable lack of any sort of even rudimentary introspection.  To describe them you have to reiterate their types and counts, which violates the DRY principle.  It's a mess all around, and there's probably more than one code out there that just uses sizeof(struct foo) MPI_BYTEs to describe them.  But here's a concrete example of where that would fail.

Now that you're sending and receiving those correctly, you decide to save them to a file, using MPI-IO (or for that matter, HDF5 or NetCDF or...).  You describe them using the same method you communicate them, of course, as sizeof(struct foo) bytes.

C tells you almost nothing about how these structs are laid out, however; the compiler is allowed to do all sorts of things to the layout, in particular inserting padding.   This generally isn't a problem for communication if all tasks are running the same code compiled with the same compiler and flags on the same sort of machine.

But now when you inevitably load that file using the same code but compiled with a different compiler, or even the same compiler but different flags, all bets are off.  The data layout may be different, resulting in garbage values - or the amount of padding may be different, causing you to read past the end of the file.

You could solve this by describing the data differently for file I/O and communications, but now it's hard to argue that this is making things simpler.  You're better off just describing the data correctly to begin with.

Comment: good example where MPI_BYTE is not the way to go. Thanks. Slicing, of course. In my case I have a 1-D array of structs, containing ints and doubles. That works fine with MPI_BYTE, I haven't found any drawbacks so far. And for the record: I am far from not wanting to learn new stuff! ;)

Comment: I agree (also) with the edit. One can avoid or well-define the padding behaviour, but as you pointed out, then the "it's easier" argument doesn't hold any longer. Anyhow, I will obviously (while running scalability tests with the working MPI_BYTE-version ;) ) post a question on the correct handling of arrays of structs in MPI.

Answer (score 1):

OK, an answer to expand on my snarky comment:

... for the same reason(s) that we don't use bytes for all our computations.  Data types are a  tremendous aid when dealing with complexity of the sort encountered in modern computer programs.  I cite in support of this assertion their presence in all programming languages above the level of assembly languages, but even at that level there are traces of data types.

The dominant languages in the domains where MPI is most used, that is Fortran, C and C++, have  data types which correspond closely to those defined in MPI.  Of course the chain of causality works in the other direction, MPI has those types because those languages do.  All those languages allow the programmer to define further data types composed of the more basic ones, again as an aid to dealing with the complexity of solving difficult problems on computers; so too does MPI support the creation of derived types.

I dispute your conclusion that dealing solely with bytes would make (MPI) programming easier, it would make my programming much harder.  If I want to send a message containing 24 integers from one process to another, I want to send a message of type integer and length 24, I don't want to be fiddling around translating that into a number of bytes.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating ;) . The thing is, MPI_BYTE made it easier for me because I couldn't get MPI_Type_struct so work... My bad, I know, but it just worked out of the box with MPI_BYTE. So I asked myself (and then everybody) whether this is a stupid idea for some reason. And... actually it is not much fiddeling, but just adding a `*sizeof(TYPE)` to the sendcount and recvcount parameter.

Comment: Ahh, so, you failed to get `MPI_Type_struct` to work so concluded that `MPI_BYTE` was the right data type to use for everything. That's an odd conclusion to draw from that particular premise.  Did it not occur to you to ask for help with your problems on SO !

Comment: Again: what is wrong with MPI_BYTE? I get why programming languages have types, I get why MPI has them. My question is, is there anything wrong, apart from an aesthetical discourse, using MPI_BYTE. I found no performance issues, endianity is not an issue in most cases, including mine, and when using complex data types, it is less to type.

Answer (score 0):

Some codes like OpenFOAM follow this bad practice:
"All calls to MPI are encapsulated in the so-called Pstream library. An object to be passed from the sender to the receiver is serialized into a contiguous block of data stripped of its type information (the receiver knows what type of data to expect). Hence all data can be passed as MPI BYTE, thus reducing the complexity of the low-level communication methods."
http://publications.rwth-aachen.de/record/569702/files/569702.pdf

Beside the discussed portability issues with MPI_BYTE the reason why all languages bring data type constructs is performance:
"Taking advantage of known data alignment is important; it allows use of wider load and store instructions. Dynamically de- tecting alignment is also possible, but hoisting this test out of the loop is another important optimization."
https://www.google.com/
https://wgropp.cs.illinois.edu/bib/papers/pdata/1999/mpidc99.ps

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use strided access patterns or are running MIMD on two different platforms, I don't see a downside to MPI_BYTE.

Derived datatypes involve a lot of overheads, and while I can imaging some optimizations for specific datatypes (mostly ints), I don't believe any of the implementations have implemented them, and if they did, they would probably be better done on the application side, as they depend heavily on the distribution of values in the data, and the application code is in a better position to estimate that distribution.

The datatype of the message does not matter during message transmission (excepting strided access), it only matters during computation. During computation the compiler can make better decisions if it knows about the datatype, but we don't lose this capability with MPI_BYTE --- we can always send from and receive into a variable of the correct type, even with MPI_BYTE. This operation locally is essentially a memcpy and does not care about the type of the data in the buffers.