# Segmentation Fault: Struct Serialisation and MPI Data Transfer in C++

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault, mpi

I am trying to send a serialised struct from one rank to another. It results in

> Segmentation fault: 11

and I have no clue from where it comes.

I have tried to locate the problem by printing out some values and the code always breaks between `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv`, but since it is segmentation fault one cannot be sure that it is the origin of the problem. Please do enlighten me.

```
int N = 11;
struct tests{
    int number;
    double *fx;
};

void locateMemoryTests(struct tests *t){
    t->fx = (double*) malloc(N*sizeof(double));
}

void he(struct tests *t, int N){
    int NRank, MyRank;
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyRank );
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &NRank );
    int st = MyRank * int(N/2);
    int en = (MyRank+1) * int(N/2) + (N%2)*MyRank;

    for (int i=st; i<en; i++){
        t->fx[i] = i*i + 5*(i + t->number);
    }
    const int nitems        = 2;
    int blocklengths[2]     = {1, N};
    MPI_Datatype types[2]   = {MPI_INT, MPI_DOUBLE};
    MPI_Datatype mpi_tests_type;
    MPI_Aint offsets[2];

    offsets[0] = offsetof(tests, number);
    offsets[1] = offsetof(tests, fx);

    MPI_Type_create_struct(nitems, blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_tests_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_tests_type);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyRank);

    if (MyRank == 0){
        struct tests send;
        send.number = t->number;
        locateMemoryTests(&send);

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
            send.fx[i] = t->fx[i];
        }   

        MPI_Send(&send, 2, mpi_tests_type, 1, 111, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    else if (MyRank == 1){
        MPI_Status status;
        struct tests recv;
        locateMemoryTests(&recv);
        MPI_Recv(&recv, 2, mpi_tests_type, 0, 111, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    MPI_Type_free(&mpi_tests_type);
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    int NRank, MyRank;
    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyRank );
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &NRank );

    struct tests tt;
    tt.number = 5;
    locateMemoryTests(&tt);

    he(&tt,N);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: MPI_Recv receives two elements, but recv variable can only hold only one?

Comment: Isn't it the purpose of serialisation, to send/receive a struct with multiple elements? Or do you mean I can only send one type of element? I learnt that "int count" in this case should be the number of the kinds of data my structure has from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165277/how-to-send-a-variable-of-type-struct-in-mpi-send

Comment: I mean you want two elements, but prepared storage only for one.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? I am new to C++ and I am not quite sure why I have prepared storage only for one instead of two.

Comment: Try struct tests recv[2]; and struct tests send[2]; and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Your recv variable can only hold single "entry" of your data. But you request two "entries". As a result MPI_Recv might overwrite some random memory. And the same situation is with MPI_Send. Your send variable contains data for single "entry", but you're telling it to send two.

Comment: Even simpler: try: MPI_Send(&send, 1, mpi_tests_type, 1, 111, MPI_COMM_WORLD); and MPI_Recv(&recv, 1, mpi_tests_type, 0, 111, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

Comment: "struct tests recv[2]" (or struct tests send[2]) is not a proper statement, I just tried. And in fact, I tried and set "int count" as 1, as you just suggested, before I changed it to 2. The change does not make any difference to the result (output).

Comment: Then i'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: It is fine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Switch 2 to 1 as i wrote. And run it via mpiexec / mpirun (depending on package you're using - on my windows i've installed msmpi and it's mpiexec): mpiexec -n 2 exe_name.exe .

Comment: Your `struct test` is not contiguous but MPI expects it to be.  Also,  this is `c`, not idiomatic `c++`.

Answer (score 1):

Your MPI derived datatype describes the following C `struct`

```
struct tests{
    int number;
    double fx[N];
};
```

but you are using a different one

```
struct tests{
    int number;
    double *fx;
};
```

if `N` is not a constant, you can either declare

```
struct tests{
    int number;
    double fx[];
};
```

and it is up to you to correctly allocate such a `struct`.

An other option is to keep the same `struct` definition, and manually `MPI_Pack()` and `MPI_Unpack()` the data to/from a temporary buffer.