# How to parallel send / receive a nested struct contains an array with MPI in C?

Tags: c, struct, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to develop my CFD solver with MPI. Basically, I have the first struct with object `cell` contains a member `U` which is related to the second struct members `ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4` each of them is a 2D array.

```
struct vectore_element{
    double ele1 [N][M];
    double ele2 [N][M];
    double ele3 [N][M];
    double ele4 [N][M];
    };

struct cell center{
     struct vector_element U;
}cell;
```

My question is, how to use scatter with these structures to divide the arrays among the tasks?
and how can I send/receive part of it from one process to another?

basically, how to create the MPI data type for such data type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send a variable of type struct in MPI\_Send()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165277/how-to-send-a-variable-of-type-struct-in-mpi-send) . Note that in your case, it would be probably a bit faster to just pack the data structure although AFAIK there is no way to do it in a portable way while keeping the data structure.

Comment: The structure is very regular, so I think you can "scatter" it in one shot. please edit your question to describe exactly what you mean by scatter, and ideally include a self contained and self tested example (i'll fill the blanks related to the datatype creation and scatter invocation if needed).